# PostSharp Nonserialized InstanceLevelAspect object in class definition

Tags: c#, serialization, postsharp

I have a problem with PostSharp. Code like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}

interface IA
{
    int a { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[IntroduceInterface(typeof(IA))]
public class Aaaa : InstanceLevelAspect, IA
{
    public int a { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[Aaaa]
class B
{
}
```

Build with PostSharp 2.0 gives class B which is Serializable with fields from interface IA.
After build with PostSharp 2.1 IA fileds are not serialized. After decompilation I get that code:

```
[Serializable]
private class B : IA
{
  [NonSerialized]
  private Aaaa <>__aspect1;

  public B()
  {
    base.\u002Ector();
    this.\u003C\u003Ez__InitializeAspects();
  }

  {...}
}
```

In version 2.0 code was almost identical with one difference. There wasn't [NonSerialized] attribute. Is there any way to get it working on 2.1  like on 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. The behavior in PostSharp 2.0 was considered buggy and fixed in 2.1. There is no way to go back to the old behavior.